# circle affine transformation

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing

I am trying to convert a region of pixels surrounded by an ellipse into an equivalent stretched circle.This basically means affine transformation. Assume I want to extract the region in light blue surrounded by the yellow ellipse, then find the equivalent circle for further processing. How can I do so using matrix multiplication, addition and subtraction only? Note that the centre of the ellipse may be another point rather than the origin, say (x0,y0). Assume that I have the values of the minor axis, major axis, the centre and the angle of rotation.

[image]

What I have in mind is to counter clockwise rotate the region by theta around the centre, then resize the region so that the length of the minor axis == length of major axis, and then rotate clockwise by theta again around the centre. Still, I don't know how to do so.

applying your answer, given in this code:

"

function [xr, yr] = ellipse2circle(x0,y0,a,b,theta, X, Y)

R1=[+cos(theta), +sin(theta), 0;
    -sin(theta), +cos(theta), 0;
        0,            0,      1];

R2=[+cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0;
    +sin(theta), +cos(theta), 0;
        0,            0,      1];

T1=[1, 0, -x0;    0, 1, -y0;    0, 0,  +1];
T2=[1, 0, +x0;    0, 1, +y0;    0, 0,  +1];
D=[1/1, 0,  0;    0, a/b, 0;    0, 0,  +1];

M=T2*R2*D*R1*T1;

V=[X, Y, ones(length(X),1)]';
U=M*V;

xr=U(1,:)';
yr=U(2,:)';

"

I got this result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you're representing points as triples of real numbers of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}{x\\y\\1}\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that transformations can be described by $3 \times 3$ matrices. Let $\theta$ be the angle from the $x$-axis counterclockwise to the major axis of your ellipse (in your example, $\theta$ is about 45 degrees, or $\pi/4$ radians). Let $a = \cos \theta$ and $b = \sin \theta$, just to save me typing. Let $(c, d)$ be the center point of the ellipse.

Let
$$
R_1 = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & 0 \\
-b & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
R_2 = \begin{bmatrix}a & -b & 0 \\
b & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
T_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -c \\ 0 & 1 & -d \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\\
T_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &  c \\ 0 & 1 &  d \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\\
$$
and
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & s/t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $s$ and $t$ are the major and minor axis lengths, respectively.

Then build the matrix
$$
M = T_2 \cdot R_2 \cdot D \cdot R_1 \cdot T_1
$$
and the transformation 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}{x\\y\\1}\end{bmatrix} \mapsto M \cdot \begin{bmatrix}{x\\y\\1}\end{bmatrix}
$$
will be the one you want.

Basically, reading from right to left in the list of matrices, this

- moves the ellipse-center to the origin
- rotates the ellipse clockwise about the origin by angle $\theta$, so that the major axis lines up with the $x$-axis.
- scales the $y$-axis up so that it's as fat in $y$ as in $x$.
- rotates counterclockwise by $\theta$.
- translates the ellipse-center back to where it used to be.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :)
but does this transform into a unit circle? if yes, then how I transform into a circle with radius equals to the major axis length? just as explained in the figure above?

Comment: You're welcome. You might mark it as a correct answer so that I get credit for it. :)

Comment: sure, but please see my edit above first. It seems that the result of this is not a circle as you can see. I believe the issue is from the D matrix. Can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you want to swap $a$ and $b$, i.e., put $b/a$ instead of $a/b$ -- maybe you've got major and minor swapped. But it looks as if perhaps $a$ and $b$ are equal and you've got no scaling at all. Try putting in a breakpoint at that line and seeing what $a$ and $b$ actually are.

Comment: I checked what you said, a and b are correct and not equal, but maybe the issue is from the D matrix.

Comment: In your example, I guess $a$ should be about $70$ and $b$ about 35. The matrix $D$ should be diagonal with (roughly) $1, 2, 1$ on the diagonal. (Indeed, you can create it with "diag(1, a/b, 1)" in matlab!)

Debugging hint: Change your line "M=T2*R2*D*R1*T1;" to "M = T1" and runit; the ellipse should be centered at the origin. Change it to "M=R1*T1;"; you should get an axis-aligned ellipse at the origin, longer in $x$ than in $y$. While you're looking at it, compute r = width/height. Change it to  "M=D*R1*T1;" Check that the 2nd diag entry of $D$ is actually r. Should be a circle. Report back.

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to debug the error (in other part of the code) and yours is perfectly working.